# Is it possible to configure Cisco ASR901 as a layer 2 VLAN switch?

Tags: switch, vlan, networking

I have been fiddling with a Cisco ASR901 for a while now, but I can't wrap my head around configuring it as a layer 2 VLAN switch. Is it not possible to configure one of its Gigabit Ethernet ports as a trunk? I can't use `switchport trunk` configuration or create a `VLAN`. I noticed that I can configure an `interface vlan`, but I, later on, found out that isn't the same thing. I can't even figure out how to designate a port for a particular VLAN.

Comment: Technically, yes, but you won't like it. (see also: bridging, "BVI") If you need a switch, buy a switch.

Comment: @Ricky My friend happens to give me this router to use and I thought I can configure it as a VLAN switch since I was able to configure for it on my Cisco E3000 router after flashing it with Tomato, of course. I never work with networking configuration on Cisco commercial routers before, so I assume it should be possible, but I have to learn it the hard way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, those are routers, not switches. You can use subinterfactes on a router interface to have layer-3 interfaces into separate networks (VLANs) as a trunk to an external switch:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 no shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.10
 encapsulation dot1Q 10              ! Tag traffic for VLAN 10
 ip address 10.0.10.0 255.255.255.0  ! Gateway for VLAN 10
 no shutdown
!
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0.20
 encapsulation dot1Q 20              ! Tag traffic for VLAN 20
 ip address 10.0.20.0 255.255.255.0  ! Gateway for VLAN 20
 no shutdown
!
! etc.
```

Comment: Perhaps not obivous to everyone: if you configure multiple ports with the same VLAN ID, there's **no switching** between them on those routed ports.

Comment: Let me get my understanding straight. What Ron Maupin said about setting up subinterfaces is similar to setting up a layer 3 VLAN interface except it is designated to a particular port rather than to all the ports. Even if I can setup a VLAN subinterface on two different ports with the same VLAN tag, there is no switching involved between the two ports as mentioned by @Zac67. Thus, the answer to my original question remains as a solid "No", correct? It is not possible to configure Cisco ASR901 to handle VLAN switching.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Right, that is not a switch, it is a router, and routers route between networks, not switch on the same network. Some routers can set up a virtual bridge. See [this question and answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/61108/8499).

Comment: It is getting more complicated than it has to be. Getting a VLAN switch or a Tomato- or OpenWRT-compatible router is more preferred choice. Thanks all.

Comment: Those are Frankenstein boxes that have a built-in switch, but the are off-topic here.